# Is it faster to read a Zip file while unzipping it (in a stream) or wait for it complete unzipping and then read it?

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

I am currently reading a CSV file from a zip file. I have 2 options to read it.

1. Read the CSV while it is being unzipped line by line by streaming it (ZipInputStream and openCSV)
2. Unzip the entire CSV file first, and then go back and read the entire thing.

Which one would be faster? I am going to perform some tests but I was wondering if anyone already knew logistically which is more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: With the same _buffered_ I/O, (1.) should be faster as disk I/O by OS and CPU/memory usage are better mixed. Also resource usage is minimal, not needing to store the entire file. But why not try it? Especially (2.) with a memory mapped file sound interesting. The hotspot compiler might skew the resulting statistics. By the way: using a zip file system `"jar:file: ..."` you can simply use `Files.copy`.

Comment: If you don't need have the CSV in your machine, I think the best solution its the first one, at performance level, openCsv read the lines you got by the input stream, and you never store an amount of CSV Files on your machine, and you avoid the process of download, store, read and delete. The problem maybe if the CSV its too big and the connection close by any reason, you lose the progress of that reading...